# Is it possible to use model/Schema of a MySQL for complex queries?

Tags: mysql, database-design

By complex queries I mean queries where you have to use at least 2 joins. Let's say I have build a schema/model of the database. Now providing that I have `users.user_id = 5` I'm asking for `logins.lastlogin`, `groups.groupname`, and `history.user_weight`. I will not write any join SQL statements, all of them will be joined at the background by the database's schema/model. Is it possible with MySQL?

Comment: use views: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html

Comment: @Omesh, but then you have to write queries into the views. Why just simply don't use it out of the view? At the and it is same as normal ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the Views idea - which, btw, is **ideal** - you could always mimic the [Oracle-materialized views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93539/what-is-the-difference-between-views-and-materialized-views-in-oracle) Branko mentioned by doing:

Create `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` triggers on each of the tables you are joining, `users`, `logins`, `groups` and `history` ; which will update a new 5th table called `lgh` (example)

So you use this new `lgh` table for the query you wanted above. It may reduce the number of rows scanned than an actual view but there's now an overhead every time data changes in any of the original 4 tables. Depending on how often you use this new lgh table vs updating the other 4, you may see some performance improvement.

**Disclaimer:**

- I don't condone this workaround, it's just an alternate suggestion for your question.
- You should really consider adding more indexes to the original 4 tables instead, maybe even for every column you use in that join query.
- This may resemble 'caching'...it's not quite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with `views`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/views.html

Comment: Noooo! First it processes all the data, even if the result is going to be one row. When you have 300000 rows it is pain in the a**; it says "execution time limit".

Comment: @george What do you mean "processes all the data". Properly indexed base tables will ensure a query on a view has good performance by **not** doing full table scans, same as with out-of-view JOINs. Are you actually asking if MySQL can "pre-JOIN" the data, a-la Oracle materialized views?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic, yes I think, "pre-JOIN"ed by MySQL itself. I don't know about the Oracle.