# update table error as data manipulation operation not legal on this view

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I wrote simple update query as below

```
update table_name set name = 'new name
```

that gave to me error

```
SQL Error: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view 01732. 00000 -  "data manipulation operation not legal on this view"
```

after that i check

```
select * FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME='table_name'
```

that list TABLE and MATERIALIZED VIEW same as the 'table_name'

I know materialized view is not possible to update but table should update

please let me know how can i update table using simple above update query

Comment: Change one of their names

Comment: @sagi Thanks for your feed back. is that possible to update without changes any of object name?

Comment: Are both of the tables in the same schema? I'm not sure if its even possible.. if not , use the schema.TableName or schema.ViewName

Comment: You can also read here about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552237/materialized-view-and-table-with-the-same-name

Comment: @sagi - as an MV is backed by a physical table and they both can/do have the same name (as you linked to), changing one of them is not a good idea and won't help. The base table of the MV has to be updated, not the MV or its backing table.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the materialized view or the [physical table it uses for storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33552513/266304). You can only update the table(s) the view is built *against*. Presumably you know those; if not you can get the view definition from the data dictionary, or with `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`.

Updating the view or it's backing table doesn't make sense anyway. Even if you were allowed to, any changes you made would be lost the next time the view is refreshed.

If you don't want the materialized view to ever be refreshed again then you could [drop that](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8020.htm) with the `preserve table` option, which would leave behind just the physical table - and you then update that. But if you change your mind you'd have to recreate the view and specify the existing table.

Comment: I don't think this is what he asked.. He wants to update the table not the view, but since there are both view and table with the same name, oracle doesn't allow it.. thats why i suggested changing one of their names

Comment: @sagi - but the table and view are different aspects of the same thing. The table the OP is trying to update is the physical storage for the logical MV. Changing the name (if it lets you after creation) won't change that. And even if you can then update the table, which I haven't ever tried, the changes would still be overwritten on refresh.

Comment: I think we understood him differently.. :) we'll have to wait for the OP to clarify