# VIEW on a table in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm looking into ClickHouse's VIEW, MATERIALIZED VIEW and LIVE VIEW.

MATERIALIZED VIEW and LIVE VIEW are pretty well described in the [official docs](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/view/).

However, VIEW on a table description is limited.
From the official docs:

```
As an example, assume you’ve created a view:

CREATE VIEW view AS SELECT ...
and written a query:

SELECT a, b, c FROM view
```

But it does not specify which table engines are supported for the table we are doing SELECT from. Also, there are no examples on usage.
Can you please provide a minimum usage example of VIEW and explain which table engines are supported for the initial table?

Concerning the difference between the VIEW and MATERIALIZED VIEW types I found this answer for Oracle and it looks like it can be applied to ClickHouse as well [What is the difference between Views and Materialized Views in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93539/what-is-the-difference-between-views-and-materialized-views-in-oracle).

Edit: Added few essential examples from tests from the link in comments:

Example 1

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS union;

create view union as select 1 as test union all select 2;

SELECT * FROM union ORDER BY test;

DETACH TABLE union;
ATTACH TABLE union;

SELECT * FROM union ORDER BY test;

DROP TABLE union;
```

Example 2:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS test_view;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;

CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    f1 Int32,
    f2 Int32,
    pk Int32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY f1
PARTITION BY pk;

CREATE VIEW test_view AS
SELECT f1, f2
FROM test_table
WHERE pk = 2;

INSERT INTO test_table (f1, f2, pk) VALUES (1,1,1), (1,1,2), (2,1,1), (2,1,2);

SELECT * FROM test_view ORDER BY f1, f2;

ALTER TABLE test_view DELETE WHERE pk = 2; --{serverError 48}

SELECT * FROM test_view ORDER BY f1, f2;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS test_view;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;
```

Comment: you can find examples of using here - https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/search?l=TSQL&q=%22create+view%22

Comment: VIEW look like just SELECT alias, MATERIEALIZED VIEW it's AFTER INSERT trigger (it described in docs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A view is just a **saved query**, nothing more.

Since you don't specify a table engine when you query a table, you don't need to specify the engine for a view. You can even combine multiple tables, each with a different table engine.

So instead of issuing a long query all the time, you can create a view for that query, which in turn will add an abstraction layer to help you to simplify your queries.

Suppose you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE events(
  device_id UInt64,
  dt DateTime,
  temp Float32
) Engine = MergeTree Order By (device_id, dt);
```

And in your application, you use this query:

```
SELECT 
  device_id, 
  toDate(dt) as day,
  count() as cnt
FROM events
GROUP BY device_id, day
```

As you can see, you are getting event counts based on the day it is produced for each `device_id`.

Now, if you use this information too frequently, putting this query in another query will make it look much complicated like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM event_detail ed
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    device_id, 
    toDate(dt) as day,
    count() as cnt
  FROM events
  GROUP BY device_id, day
) daily_event_counts
ON ed.device_id = daily_event_counts.device_id
```

So you create a view for the subquery like this:

```
CREATE VIEW daily_event_counts AS
SELECT 
  device_id, 
  toDate(dt) as day,
  count() as cnt
FROM events
GROUP BY device_id, day;
```

After that, writing a query will be much easier:

```
SELECT *
FROM event_detail ed
INNER JOIN daily_event_counts 
ON ed.device_id = daily_event_counts.device_id
```

As you can see, it is just a named query, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for the examples and explanations.